Can't test Flow<PagingData<T>>.cachedIn
In my viewmodel I get a Flow<PagingData> by calling the use case in charge of doing it, and then caching it, as recommend it by android developer's guide, like this:
val bestRatedRepos: Flow<PagingData<UiMovie>> = getPagedBestRatedMoviesUseCase()
    .cachedIn(viewModelScope)

The problem is that when I am testing, this simple test fails:
@Test
fun `getPagedBestRatedMoviesUseCase is called in constructor`() = runTest {
    val data = viewModel.bestRatedMovies.asSnapshot()
    assertEquals(mockList, data)
}

The thing is that if I remove the .cachedIn(viewModelScope), the test works. Otherwise, the error is the following:
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 10s, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: [ScopeCoroutine{Active}@4de21390]
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$2$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt:349)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$2$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt:333)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.InvokeOnCancelling.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1431)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1477)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:799)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:759)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:675)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelCoroutine(JobSupport.kt:662)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCoroutine.run(Timeout.kt:159)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase$DelayedRunnableTask.run(EventLoop.common.kt:501)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
at app//kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor.run(DefaultExecutor.kt:109)
at java.base@17.0.10/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


This might be helpful: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/324108012.
I collected the paging data via the Flow testing collection API, turned it into Flow, and got a snapshot value of it.
